# SQL - Removing Row Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following information:

[image]

Is there a way to remove all groups which have multiple IDs? For example group 3 would be removed because it consists of ID 1 and 2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple, portable and efficient approach is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.group = t.group and t1.id <> t.id
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(group, id)`.

Side note: `group` is a SQL keyword (as in `group by`), hence not a good choice for a column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to remove all groups having multiple IDs

```
Delete from <your_table_name> where Group in (select Group from <your_table_name> group by Group,ID having count(*) > 1)
```

inner query will return Group having multiple IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute below query:

```
select id,group from table where group in 
(
select group from(
select group,count(distinct id) as cn from table group by 1 having cn=1) a
)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

select * from temp where group in (
select groups from temp group by id,group having count(1)<3)

delete from temp where group in (
select groups from temp group by id,group having count(1)<3)